# How to disable mouse Events on React Component (echarts-for-react)?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, dom-events, mouseevent, onclicklistener

I created a treemap in React using echarts-for-react (https://github.com/hustcc/echarts-for-react). The treemap works and renders properly on the page but it won't 'lock' to the page. If you select it with your mouse it moves, if you scroll near it, it zooms in and out and you generally can use your mouse to move it around the page from its original location. If you refresh the page it returns to its original location.

I would like to disable all mouse events on the component so that it just locks to the page but since this package doesn't take an `onClick` prop etc. not really sure what to do. I've never ran into this issue before and the library seems to take a `onEvents` prop; that takes a dictionary. I've written something like this:

```
const preventEventsHandler = () => {
  console.log('prevent events handler called');
}

const onEvents = {
  "click": preventEventsHandler,
};

return <ReactECharts onEvents={onEvents} />;
```

If you run this code everything still runs properly and the function doesn't get called till it's clicked on (I can tell this part works because the print statement is returning in the console) but i'm not sure how you could get event properties out (to use a `e.preventDefault` or something like that) or how to generally just let this stay locked to the page. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

adding style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }} worked to get the mouse events disabled